# passing parameters in renderComponent method in symfony

Tags: symfony1

I am trying to pass three parameters in renderComponent method.

like: `$this->renderComponent('toolbox','features', array('id' => $this->id));`

and in my 'features' component I am trying to get the parameter from request.

`public function executeFeatures(sfWebRequest $request) {

      $this->id = $request->getParameter('id');
}` and i am not getting the value of id.

Is there something wrong in the above implementation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no request passed to a component. The variables you are looking for are already assigend to the controller to be passed to the view with the standard symfony magic, so you would access them by: `$this->id`.

If you actually need to pull somehting out of the request you should be able to do:

`$this->getRequest()->getParameter('some_req_param_name');`